# How to adjust volume balance on a USB audio device when it doesn't have that option?

Tags: windows, audio, usb, dac

The device in question is a [Topping G5](https://www.audiosciencereview.com/forum/index.php?threads/topping-g5-review-portable-dac-hp-amp.36542), but the issue happens with many USB devices on Windows that have their own inbuilt DAC, but not all. For example my [Aune T1](https://www.head-fi.org/showcase/aune-t1.14924/reviews) gives me individual channel control just fine.

Normally to adjust audio balance, you open the Properties window for the device, goto the Levels tab, click the Balance button, and adjust the individual channel levels.

For this device in that window, I'm seeing a single slider for the volume, the mute button the right of it. The "Balance" button simply doesn't exist, and there's no other device level control underneath it either. Despite that, sending stereo sound data to it works fine, you can hear left-channel data in the left ear, etc.

It's currently using the default windows-provided driver. I've tried using the Topping driver; no change. Then rolling back, again no change.

I've tried writing my own program, importing the NAudio library and controlling the channels, no luck: it only registers a single channel in windows.

I've tried using the small program "setvol" but the same issue presents itself: it only sees only one channel.

I give this a try, which sounded promising: https://superuser.com/questions/1643029/unable-to-change-audio-balance-on-windows-10
But this is only for one there's visibly dual (left+right) channels and the UI has locked them together, not for when there's only one "channel" controlling the signal that goes to the DAC.

I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: You have tried it similar but try it this way: If you go into your Device Manager and disable this audio device for a short time and then search for a suitable driver by right clicking on it - Update Driver> Search for driver software on my computer> Let me choose from a list of device drivers on my computer. Which selection is available to you here? I had the same phenomenon and did not select the Realtek High Definition driver (or similar) but a specific one. This should give you the desired settings after a reboot.

Comment: Otherwise you can try Simplesndvol "https://winaero.com/simplesndvol/"

Comment: Thanks @Chewbacca, but I've already tried simplesndvol - it gives me a generic .net error msg on startup... presumably because it's as frustrated by the single presented channel as I am. 
And yep, have tried playing around with manually installing/uninstalling drivers. No success.

Comment: I would love to help you. Can you may give me the complete error message here?

Comment: Awesome, thanks!
************** Exception Text **************
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at simplesndvol.Form1.SetToolTips()
   at simplesndvol.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
(cut)

Comment: So I have now tested several systems and installed simplesndvol on them: I have not received a NET error or any other error like you received.
Can you uninstall and delete simplesndvol once incl. all created folders and install again if necessary?

Comment: Appreciate the effort but yeah part of the testing process is constant install/uninstall of these softwares.
I'm guessing the "index outside the array" is the program trying to address two channels when there's only one available - I get similar errors from NAudio.

Comment: Okay, if thats the case have you tried Equalizer APO ? In this program you can set for which device the EQ should be installed. If you go into the configuration editor, you have many more options than just the balance control. Maybe this will help you with your current problem.

Comment: I gave Equalizer APO a whirl. It looks pretty cool, but doesn't seem to apply the settings to the device. A google suggests I need to make sure Enhancements are enabled in the Windows device properties, but again, that option simply isn't there.
I'm 95% sure it's a driver issue and maybe certain parts of it aren't registering for whatever reason? But I don't know how to address that.